# Facebook open graph meta tag og:image issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have WP blog with Facebook opengraph meta tags. http://comicfotos.ru/zakhvatyvayushhiy-rassvet-ozero_slovenia/ But Facebook does not take first image of the article. What did I make wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged the url at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ? Is it still wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This could have happened because of two reasons:

1) You didn't specify the first image in your **og:image** meta tag. If this is the case, Facebook makes a best effort guess and picks an arbitrary image on your website.

2) If you did specify the **og:image** meta-tag, and this happened to you ONLY the first time you shared your URL, it's because Facebook won't show the image until the crawler hasn't fetched it.

A way to have it show consistently every time is to specify the **og:image:width** and **og:image:height** meta tags as well.

Here's a sample, taken from http://ogp.me/

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

And here's the official Facebook documentation mentioning this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices